# How to install tailwindcss with webpacker in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, tailwind-css, webpacker

i want to install tailwindcss with webpacker with Ruby on Rails.

I followed some tutorials but there were all outdated.

I was getting webpacker error, or the css would not load.

I correctly have both `stylesheet_pack_tag` and `javascript_pack_tag` in my `app/views/layouts/application.html.slim`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
rails webpacker:install
yarn add tailwindcss
npx tailwindcss init
```

then in `postcss.config.js` add `require('tailwindcss')`:

```js
module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    require('postcss-import'),
    require('postcss-flexbugs-fixes'),
    require('tailwindcss'),
    require('postcss-preset-env')({
      autoprefixer: {
        flexbox: 'no-2009'
      },
      stage: 3
    })
  ]
}
```

and in `app/javascript/css/application.scss`:

```
@import "tailwindcss/base";
@import "tailwindcss/components";
@import "tailwindcss/utilities";
```

then in `app/javascript/packs/application.js`:

```js
import "../css/application.scss"
```

Comment: Is this answer works for Tailwind CSS V2.0 that requires PostCSS 8 ?

Comment: I don't know, I'm on tailwindcss 1.9.6